# Save function in tuple without executing

Tags: python, string, function, tuples

I have a tuple like the following:

```
self.tagnames = (('string', self.do_anything()),)
```

It should execute a specific function if a string matches to another.
However, when I initialize `self.tagnames`, it seems to execute the function already.

How can I fix my issue without executing the function on startup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
self.tagnames = (('string', self.do_anything),)
```

The `()` is a function call. If you want to defer the call until later, and just include the function reference without the parens like so.

Comment: There is a bit more magic that just returning a function reference (the problem is `self` parameter that will be included in what `self.do_anything` returns).

Answer (score 2):

```
self.tagnames = (('string', self.do_anything),)
```

You invoke a function by using parens with an argument list:

`len` is a function, `len(s)` is invoking that function on the argument `s`. Simply using the function's name gets you the function. Leave off the parenthesized argument list, and you are no longer invoking the function.

Answer (score 1):

You should just remove the parenthesis:

```
self.tagnames = (('string', self.do_anything),)
```

Clearly `self.do_anything()` calls the method immediately, instead `self.do_anything` returns what in Python is called a "bound method", i.e. it's a callable object to which you can pass just the parameters (if any) and that will result in calling the method on the specific instance.

Comment: I don't think so.  It looks like someone came through and downvoted the question and all of the answers with no explanation.